# django-The page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-middleware

I have a middleware that check user profile. If auth user doesn't have a profile, then redirect to user profile. My browser displays the error `The page isn’t redirecting properly`.

```
class Check(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = request.user
            try:
                profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id = user)
                if profile:
                    pass
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile/')
```

I'm use `django-allauth`.

Comment: I believe that inside `HttpResponseRedirect` you should use the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) function. That should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you might have an infinite redirect loop. Check the request path, and do not redirect if the user is trying to access `/accounts/profile/`.

```
class Check(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.path != '/accounts/profile/':
            ...
```

Comment: tank my brother

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using The Right view, in my case i was using:

**view**

```
class Blog_View(View):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog.html'
```

***instead of***

**Listview**

```
class Blog_View(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your secret key in setting.py I solved this problem with to remove get_random_secret_key().

Before

```
SECRET_KEY = env.str("SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())
```

After
SECRET_KEY = env.str("SECRET_KEY")

```
Now Im using unique SECRET_KEY and it works fine in prod service.
```